# Change all characters on web page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, safari-extension

I'm trying to make a Safari extension which should change all `й` characters to `и`. I've written such inject-script:

```
var content = document.body.innerHTML;
var updatedContent = "";

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var c = content.charAt(i);
    if (c == 'й') {
        c = 'и';
    }
    updatedContent += c;
}

document.body.innerHTML = updatedContent;
```

But the first problem is that many websites that use AJAX for page content loading appears without my changes.

The second problem is that many websites stoped to respond to mouse clicks. Nobody uses Russian letters for coding, only for text. So, I am sure that problem is not because of my script changes both source code and text.

But, it seems like I do it wrong.

Any ideas how to make it working better?